# How to schedule task for Microsoft Account user

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2777388/you-cannot-schedule-tasks-by-using-a-microsoft-account-in-task-schedul

This page suggests that creating task for MS Account user is possible using /ru /rp parameters.

`/create /tn Wallpaper /tr "C:\Users\user1\rw.bat" /sc once /st 22:10:00 /ru user@hotmail.com /rp pass`

With the above command the task is created. I can also trigger it to run with `schtasks /run /tn Wallpaper` and I'm getting message "success: attempted to run task". However the script didn't run. May it be account issue?

I want to call nodejs script, it should work using `"path\to\node.exe path\to\script.js"` but i moved to bat just to be sure. Calling bat by double clicking it works as intended.

Is this really possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The article written by Microsoft is indeed accurate.  The limitation of being unable to use an account linked to Microsoft Account only applies to the UI.  When you run the command, is the task created, and more importantly does the task run?

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the question. Command itself works, but task does not invoke my script.

Answer (score 0):

In my case specifying the username as pcname\username (e.g. MyPC\Thomas) worked. I didn't have to go through the commandline to create the task, just doing it "as usual" in the app/management console worked.